# Unable to access props.index even though props has index

Tags: react-native

I have a list i need to render with a button that will onPress save a value to the store then change to a different route but the problem is that when I `console.log(props)` i get `{"index":1, "title":"hello world"}` but if I do `console.log(props.index)` i get blank it doesn't give me a value why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error must come from something else. There is no problem with what you are describing, such as :

```js
var props = {
  "index": 1,
  "something": "else"
}

console.log(props);
console.log(props.index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an other prop name like "myCustomIndex", i'm not sure but maybe this keyword is not allowed in props.